# DIscoverying Oauth Server through Eureka

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Looking at the following example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso, the URL to the authorization/authentication server is predefined in application.yml.

The question is, if I have the config server and eureka in my architecture, can the SSO service discover the authserver through Eureka as opposed to having it predefined in the configuration file?

I tried changing the config file by using the service name instead of localhost:8080. It didn't work.

```
oauth2:
    client:
        tokenUri: http://authserver/uaa/oauth/token
        authorizationUri: http://authserver/uaa/oauth/authorize
        clientId: acme
        clientSecret: acmesecret
     resource:
        jwt:
             keyUri: http://authserver/uaa/oauth/token_key
             id: openid
             serviceId: ${PREFIX:}resource
```

Along the same thinking process, instead of providing keyUri to JWT, can I populate the public key directly through the configuration server? WHat would be the syntax?

Edit: After some more tests, it appears that tokenUri and authorizationUri are very well discoverable. I can use the service name instead of localhost:8080. The only question now is what to do with keyUri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. As per the edit above, the tokenUri and the authorizationUri are discoverable. Instead of using keyUri, I use keyValue. This way, the SSO server does not need to connect to the Oauth server to fecth the key. I then populate the keyValue using the configuration server in the way any other value would be populated. This renders my authorization server completely discoverable.

Comment: I'd be happy to update the sample and add some documentation if this really works. I'd like to qualify first though: I would expect that using a service name instead of a hostname will only work if you are using the `RestTemplate` from Spring Cloud ribbon support. But the SSO feature relies on using an `OAuth2RestTemplate` that is built by Spring OAuth, so I don't understand how that could know about the load balancer.

Comment: I just tested again and it seems to work just fine. Now, my POM is significantly different than the one in github. Would changing dependencies be enough to force SSO to use RestTemplate as opposed to OauthRestTemplate? If so, that could be the reason.

Comment: I can't imagine how that would help. Can you share your project?

Comment: OK. Let me find a way to share. Actually running into an issue with @EnableOAuth2Sso and RestTemplate right now. As soon as that annotation is added to the project, Spring starts complaining about not being able to autowire RestTemplate. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: I sent you an invite to a bitbucket project that includes configserver, eureka, auth server, sso server and a pom project that includes shared dependencies. The project can be executed AS IS.

Comment: Can I get an invite to the source too.  Having problems discovering authserver.  I just get ERR_DNS errors like its not trying to look it up.

Comment: Can I get also an invite if possible ?

Comment: I would also be interested in an invite. Could you perhaps just provide the project link here so that others can find it, too?